# How to make an action run in the background?

Tags: actions

In my web site which I am creating, I have some tasks which are quite heavy, etc.

```
 add_action('add_attachment', [$this, 'mediaAdd']);
```

What mediaAdd does it grabs a file from the media libray and uploads to Amazon S3. If the file is heavy, the UI will freeze. What is the best way to handle such task in the background in wordpress?

Comment: You can use cron, create a list of files that need to be downloaded and then run this action either on demand or scheduled. Using cron is the best method

Comment: if you upload an image and expect it to be served from S3 than you most likely just need to wait. The situation is much more complex than just doing something in the background. In any case there any many plugins that do that so you should inspect their code and learn how to do it

Comment: Instead of `mediaAdd` execute a different function `exampleFunction`  which keeps a record of all the files that are too large and then save the list somewhere, so exampleFunction is exactly same as the mediaAdd, the only difference is that it won't download large files and instead save a list which will be processed periodically in background by your `largeFileDownload` function.

Comment: I do not need to use this heavy file in UI. I make a thumbnail which I display for the user so the heavy image has some time to get to S3 without any latency for the user.